# Collect Data VI, Setup NML DAQ VI

Tags: labview

I am looking for the following VIs:

- Collect Data VI (the missing Sub Vi is the AI Wave Form (Scan array) VI i believe but I'm not entirely sure)
- Setup NML DAQ VI (missing sub VIs are create virtual channel, timing vi (Sample Clock), Create Task vi and clear task vi.)

I'm new to Labview and Im trying to fix up a pre used program so I dont know whether I should make these VIs from scratch, download a driver or download their Sub VIs from somewhere. Please help! Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 2):

These VIs are in likely to be in DAQmx, the drivers for data acquisition devices. You can download it [here](http://search.ni.com/nisearch/app/main/p/bot/no/ap/tech/pg/1/sn/catnav%3adu,n8:3478.41.181.5495,ssnav%3asup/)

[Direct link of current version for windows](http://ftp.ni.com/support/softlib/multifunction_daq/nidaqmx/9.3.0/NIDAQ930f2.exe), 9.3f2